# Clear Input Value with CSS Only

Tags: html, css

I have an input as so:

```
<input type='text' id='mytext' name='mytext' value='Chocolate' />
```

Is it possible that on `#mytext:focus` it will clear the value with CSS only. I know I can use jQuery to do this with `$("#mytext").val("")` but I want to do this with CSS only. I don't mind if it is only supported in modern browsers as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try like ;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click on textbox.</p>
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'enter your name') { this.value = ''; }" value="enter your name" />
</body>
</html>
```

Or you can use HTML5 placeholder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <style>
input{
width: 390px;
height: 30px;
font-size: 14px;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0 0 5px;   /* for chrome & Safari browser */
-moz-box-shadow:  0 0 5px;   /* for Mozilla web browser*/
border-style: none;
margin-top: 5px;
padding-left:10px;
}
</style>
   <!-- include javascript file here-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main"> 
    <!-- first div for form -->
      <div id="first">
       <h1>Please fill this form and click reset button.</h1>
        <p></p><hr/>

        <form id="myform">
        <label> First name : </label></br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"/><br><br>       
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He said css only!

Answer (score 0):

use a `placeholder` and when you type the default value will go and your new value will appear as you type

```html
<input type='text' id='mytext' name='mytext' placeholder='Chocolate' />
```

Comment: I will be typing into the input box and it needs to clear anything that is typed into that box by clicking on another input box.

Comment: that means you want to clear the input value of its sibling ?

Comment: i dont think it is possible with `css` javascript or jquery will be good

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so it possible with `CSS` only;
One solution is to use `Placeholder`, and style it like look like a value.
Otherwise you can try this;

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57mvs3x8/)**

```
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'value') { this.value = ''; }" value="value" />
```

**Styling a placeholder:**

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```